# Satellizer not pass Authenication header to my API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, satellizer, http-token-authentication

So I am currently working locally, I have an API (Laravel). Everything is working great, I can login using Facebook, I get a JWT from my API and that is saved in local storage, however, after being logged and API calls do contain the 'Authorization: Bearer + token' header.

From what I understand in the docs, this should be all set up and ready to go without and config in the app side of things?

Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
   $authProvider.tokenPrefix = '';

    // Facebook
    $authProvider.facebook({
        clientId: '219883618025157',
         url: APICONFIG.url + APICONFIG.version + 'auth/facebook/callback'
    });
```

**Example API Call:**

```
$http.get(APICONFIG.url + APICONFIG.version + 'auth/logout').then(function(response) {}, function(error) {});
```

**The request headers in the above request:**

```
GET /v1/auth/logout HTTP/1.1
Host: api.myapp.app
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://myapp.app
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://myapp.app/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this was my silly mistake, I was essentially logging the user out of my AngularJS application (removing the token) and then POSTing to my API which off course wouldn't contain the token as it was being unset before my call.